# copy date to other user

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some data, like this:And I want to copy the data to other user. But how to do that? The data is a list of products

```
select WL.Name, WL.ID,WL.UserID, WP.ID, WP.WishListID
from bdWishList WL
join
bdWishListProducts WP
on
WL.ID = WP.WishListID
where WL.UserID = '47512'
```

But now I want to copy the data from userid=47512 to userid=47509, like this:

```
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3437    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3438    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3439    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3440    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3441    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3442    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3443    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3444    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3445    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3446    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3447    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3448    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3449    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3450    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3451    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3452    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295  267 47512   3453    267
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3454    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3455    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3456    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3457    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3458    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3459    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3460    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3461    268
rotterdam oudedijk 295 evohome  268 47512   3462    268
waddinxveen     276 47512   3621    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3622    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3623    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3624    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3625    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3626    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3627    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3628    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3629    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3630    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3631    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3632    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3633    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3634    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3635    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3636    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3637    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3638    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3639    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3640    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3641    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3642    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3643    276
waddinxveen     276 47512   3644    276
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3645    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3646    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3647    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3648    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3649    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3650    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3651    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3652    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3653    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3654    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3655    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3656    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3657    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3658    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3659    277
waddinxveen raditoren   277 47512   3660    277
```

But how to copy the data?

Thank you

So is it now clear what I mean?

The two create table scripts are:

USE [Dynamicweb-Verploegen-Test]
GO

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[bdWishListProducts]    Script Date: 06/24/2016 09:26:32 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bdWishListProducts](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [WishListID] [int] NULL,
    [ProductID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ProductVariantID] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Quantity] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [ShopID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_bdWishListProducts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bdWishListProducts]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_bdWishListProducts_bdWishList] FOREIGN KEY([WishListID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[bdWishList] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bdWishListProducts] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_bdWishListProducts_bdWishList]
GO
```

and:

```
USE [Dynamicweb-Verploegen-Test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[bdWishList]    Script Date: 06/24/2016 09:28:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bdWishList](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [DateModified] [datetime] NULL,
    [Active] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_bdOrderTemplate] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bdWishList] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_bdWishList_DateCreated]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateCreated]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bdWishList] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_bdWishList_DateModified]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [DateModified]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[bdWishList] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_bdWishList_default]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [Active]
GO
```

@gofr1
the problem is this:

```
 user1: 
    userlist1: products: user1List1product1, user1List1product2
    userlist2, products: user1List2Product3, user1List2Product4

    User2:
    Userlist3, products: user2List3Prodcuts5
    Userlist4, products User2Lis4tProduct6

    Then I copy the lists from User1 to User2:

    lists user2:
    userlist1: products: user1List1product1, user1List1product2
    userlist2, products: user1List2Product3, user1List2Product4

    Userlist3, products: user2List3Prodcuts5, User2Lis4tProduct6
    Userlist4, products : empty and it has to be:
 Userlist4, products User2Lis4tProduct6
```

So all the list are copied, but not the products.

Comment: Bro what do u mean by copy... do you wish to export the data in CSV or Excel ?

Comment: Try insert- select stamente changing UserID. Post the tables structure for more advice

Comment: please look here  on how to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: In the sql database. But then the productList with the products has to be copied/past from UserId=47512 to UserId =47512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on create scripts of your table I suggest you at first insert into `bdWishList`:

```
DECLARE @wlid int = <>

INSERT INTO bdWishList ([UserID],[Name]) --[DateCreated],[DateModified],[Active] will get default values
SELECT  47509,
        WL.Name  --Maybe you should use another name
FROM bdWishList WL
WHERE WL.UserID = 47512 and WL.ID = @wlid
```

Then get ID of inserted row:

```
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @id = IDENT_CURRENT('bdWishList')
```

And then insert data in `bdWishListProducts`:

```
INSERT INTO bdWishListProducts ([WishListID], [ProductID], [ProductVariantID], [Quantity], [ShopID])
SELECT  @id, 
        WP.ProductID,
        WP.ProductVariantID,
        WP.Quantity,
        WP.ShopId
FROM bdWishList WL
INNER JOIN bdWishListProducts WP
    ON WL.ID = WP.WishListID
where WL.UserID = 47512 and WL.ID = @wlid
```

If you want to copy many *wish lists* at once:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (  
    [NewId] int,  
    [OldId] int
)

MERGE INTO ##bdWishList as target
USING (
    SELECT  ID,
            47509 as UserID, 
            WL.Name  --Maybe you should use another name
    FROM ##bdWishList WL
    WHERE WL.UserID = 47512
    ) AS source 
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT ([UserID],[Name])
    VALUES (source.[UserID],source.[Name])
    OUTPUT inserted.ID, source.ID 
    INTO @temp;


INSERT INTO bdWishListProducts ([WishListID], [ProductID], [ProductVariantID], [Quantity], [ShopID])
SELECT  t.[NewId], 
        WP.ProductID,
        WP.ProductVariantID,
        WP.Quantity,
        WP.ShopId
FROM bdWishList WL
INNER JOIN bdWishListProducts WP
    ON WL.ID = WP.WishListID
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [NewId],[OldId] FROM @temp) t
    ON t.[OldId] = WL.ID
where WL.UserID = 47512
```

Comment: HI, I only get this error: The multi-part identifier "WL.ID" could not be bound. on this line: WL.ID

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot that there is MERGE with INSERT required. Check it out!

Comment: Thank you. But Then I get this error: Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

Comment: You use SQL Server 2008? The MERGE statement should work. Check this query `select compatibility_level from sys.databases where name = 'your database name here'`

Comment: If you got only 3 wishlists, just copy them one by one. I add `@wlid` variable to the first part of my answer. You can determine first wishlist id and run script, then second and run and third, etc.

Comment: Oke, thank you. I will try it later. And then I will let you know

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be a Insert into statement  ala :

```
Insert into bdWishListProducts (
select  @NewID, WP.ID, WP.WishListID
from bdWishList WL
join
bdWishListProducts WP
on
WL.ID = WP.WishListID
where WL.UserID = '47512'
```

(Assuming you don't want a separate wishlist ID

a More sensible approach would be

```
Insert into bdWishList (name, id, userid) Values ('NEWNAME', 'NewID', 'USERID') 

Insert into bdWishListProducts (
select   WP.ID, NEWID 
from bdWishList WL
join
bdWishListProducts WP
on
WL.ID = WP.WishListID
where WL.UserID = '47512'
)
```

Obviously - you will need to ensure that all the required fields are provided - I've just typed this as quickly as possible

Comment: Thank you. But the data: bdWishList with the products in the list: bdWishListProducts have to be copied past from userid=47512 to userid=47509

Comment: and where is closing bracket?

Comment: Sorry Your correct it needs a closing bracket - sorry I've been distracted.

Comment: in the example code replace "USERID" with the user you want to copy to, "New ID " needs to be a valid wishlist ID thats not been used, and "newName" could basically be anything - (Im making assumptionas about your db structure here)